# use useRef to get updated height on children changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an accordian component, I use useRef to measure the children height. But I have functionality on the children to change the content, but the children's measurement didn't update, unless I click on the toggle again.

```
const Accordian = ({ isOpen, children }) => {
  const chilRef = useRef();
  const [childHeight, setChildHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      const childHeight = chilRef.current && chilRef.current.scrollHeight;
      setChildHeight(childHeight);
    }
  }, [isOpen]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: isOpen ? "block" : "none"
      }}
    >
      <div ref={chilRef}>
        {children}

        <br />
        <br />
        <div>ChildHeight: {childHeight}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [boxOpen, setBoxOpen] = useState(true);
  const [expandChild, setExpandChild] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setBoxOpen(prev => !prev);
        }}
      >
        Toggle box
      </button>
      <Accordian isOpen={boxOpen}>
        {expandChild ? (
          <>
            <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
            <div>This has more content</div>
            <div>More content......</div>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div>Hello</div>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setExpandChild(true);
              }}
            >
              Expand child
            </button>
          </>
        )}
      </Accordian>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-rgb-vcqnz?file=/src/App.js:83-1435

How do I get the children height every time the children changed?

Comment: `useRef` doesn't enforce re-rendering of the component. Have your tried binding it to `childHeight` instead?

Comment: I bind it to child, what do you mean bind to childHeight?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the children to hook's dependencies.

```
const Accordian = ({ children }) => {
  const chilRef = useRef();
  const [childHeight, setChildHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (children) {
      const childHeight = chilRef.current && chilRef.current.scrollHeight;
      setChildHeight(childHeight);
    }
  }, [children]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={chilRef}>
        {children}

        <br />
        <br />
        <div>ChildHeight: {childHeight}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-hooks-u8pnt

Comment: what is..if children not increase but some other content like header in `Accordian`??

Comment: put header within accordian, then the header become a part of the children.

Comment: lol.. justifying ur answer :) and adding `[children]` performance lack, since every time it will change. You can console inside. Even parent any change, this will update.

Comment: use data, instead of window.height, with `useLayoutEffect.`

Comment: how does it look like? I don't get you.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong...First-time toggle did not change value of `isOpen`, so `useEffect never run`. Once u change to false then it `re-run useEffect`.

You have to move to expend logic in the child component. Or `use forwarRef` to calculate `height in parent`.

**Logs:**

```
Before: useEffecttrue 0 
Before: useEffecttrue 0 
Inside: useEffecttrue 73 
Before: useEffecttrue 73 
Before: useEffecttrue 73 
expend... 
Before: useEffecttrue 73 
Before: useEffecttrue 73 
toggle::... 
Before: useEffectfalse 73 
Before: useEffectfalse 73 
Inside: useEffectfalse 0 
Before: useEffectfalse 0 
Before: useEffectfalse 0
```

**Sample Solution:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-allen-evmhb?file=/src/App.js:0-1515

Comment: I click expand child I see the same value as before. Is your demo working?

Comment: yes.. i dint fix the code.. you have to check your logic what you want.. I just highlighted issue.

Comment: Hope, you know ur issue. Now check my suggestion. Based on that you can modify code.

Comment: then this shouldn't be the answer. my question is solid. how to get children height when the children changed using ref, that's all.

Comment: see my answer below. much more simpler.